# Using "seldomly"

Tags: word-usage, adverbs, is-it-a-word

I'm not a native English speaker.

If at all possible I try to use spell checkers while writing anything on the web hence using one in Firefox as well. Whenever I try to write "seldomly" it highlights it as incorrect.

Is it really?

Example:

> This particular word is seldomly used.

Comment: Just for perspective, I am a native speaker of English, and I can remember the incident where I first came across the word 'seldom' (I was about 11 years old reading some Charlie Brown comic). I think that was the last time, too (maybe once in Jane Austen or some translation of Dostoyevsky). English speakers (at least AmE) **hardly ever** use that word.

Comment: I seldom use "seldomly". (And when I do, it's quite seldom, I assure you.)

Comment: "Seldom" is a perfectly normal part of my (BrE) vocabulary. "Seldomly" is not.

Comment: @Colin: I hope what I said about 'hardly ever' is not taken as a value judgement. I'm only reporting what I think (as a native AmE speaker) is the usage pattern for the particular vocabulary item, in order to tell someone (possibly a foreign language learner of English) what is appropriate (that is, if they use 'seldom' in the US (or at least in my idiolect), it'll sound weird (even in the highest, educated registers)). Your response is probably in the same vein, (that it's perfectly fine  I just want to make it clear what my perspective is just in case.

Comment: @Mitch: I suppose it could be more of a British English vocabulary word. I'm sure I've heard it few times when I was in Britain.

Comment: Native English speakers will seldom use seldomly.

Comment: I am a native speaker of English, born and lived in America.  I think "seldom" is the proper word, and "seldomly" sounds weird.

Comment: I'm a native British English speaker and initially the OP's example didn't sound odd to me, but I agree that *seldom* in his example would have sounded equally acceptable. One could use *rarely* instead of *seldomly* if thought preferable.

Comment: @Mitch: To be clear, although I do agree with the general consensus on the correct usage of the word *seldomly* within this discussion, I find it a little strange that you claim that the use of *seldom* would sound weird "even in the highest, educated registers". I am in academia (split time between two prestigious universities in North America) and would not hesitate to use *seldom*. I am not the kind of person who feels the need to throw around 18th century vocab and eloquent sentence structure to describe the aroma of the leftovers in the lunch-room microwave in order to sound educated.

Comment: I can't imagine now what people think of me because "seldom" and sometimes even "seldomly" are in my vocabulary. lol!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Contrary to your (very reasonable) gut feeling, [seldom is an adverb](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/seldom), even though it doesn't end in *-ly*.

Comment: And thus, that particular word is seldom used.

Comment: Wow. It surely sounds strange... is seldom used. ;) But thanks for clearing this up for me. I guess I'll have to obey to those underlined corrections... ;)

Answer (score 11):

Teachers will tell you to use *seldom*, which is an adverb already so doesn't need *-ly*. But Google Books will tell you people have been using *seldomly* since the eighteenth century and still use it today — though considerably less than *seldom*.

So the best advice (in my opinion) is to use *seldom*. But *seldomly* is not **wrong**.

Comment: Depends on your definition of "wrong"... but I get your point.

Comment: +1: Thanks for that. I knew I've seen *-ly* being used before (and not by me). This explains lots.

Comment: As I understood this answer it's probably *grammatically wrong* but not *colloquially wrong*...

Comment: Yes, wrong in terms of 'proper' English (whatever that is these days) but probably acceptable by most. Still, more and more mistakes are becoming 'acceptable so it is definitely best avoided. Go with 'seldom'.

Answer (score 2):

As already pointed out, the word "seldom" is mainly an adverb, even though it can be used as an adjective in some cases. And although "seldom" may be seldom in every day language, "seldomly" occurs even more seldom.

This stands in contrast to the word "often", which in relation to "seldom" is used very often.

*Note that both "seldom" and "often" are adverbs, but that none of them ends in "-ly" which adverbs almost always do otherwise.*

[image]

Comment: I hate gifs. They're fun for about 0.50 seconds then they are dull, irritating and eventually nauseating. Is there a way to convert a gif in jpg format?

Comment: @Mari-Lou A: Sure there is. You can open the image in MS Paint and resave it as a jpg image, or as a png.

Comment: I think the comment comparing to *often* is telling. I've never been tempted to write *oftenly*. (However, I ended up on this page having been struck with doubts after typing *seldomly* into a document)

Comment: @user96913 thanks. That's how I will remember to never use _seldomly_ again: `seldom` is the antonym of  `often`

Answer (score 2):

In all honesty,the word 'seldomly' is not acceptable in contemporary British English.Attaching the suffix -ly   to 'seldom' to create an adverb,in my scholarly opinion,constitutes a redundancy of the highest order,simply because 'seldom' is already an adverb.