# Is 'Seldom I am wrong' correct or wrong?

Tags: grammaticality

Please advise if 'Seldom I am wrong' correct or wrong?

Comment: A more idiomatic approach is _I am [seldom](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19460/using-seldomly/19461) wrong._

Answer (score -2):

Grammatically it is correct.  As these are

> Often I am wrong.
>   Sometimes I am wrong.
>   Frequently I am wrong.

But inverted word order is also correct.

> Seldom am I wrong.

Perhaps better than both is this:

> I am seldom wrong.

Comment: No; (unlike 'often' etc) 'seldom' is a negative polarity item and triggers mandatory inversion.